# Change windows phone 8 state to Silent

Tags: windows, mobile

How can i change windows phone 8 state to silent for a specific time? I read on the internet some said you don't have access as it's security thing  . I was thinking to set the ringtone to a mute ringtone but that wont stop apps from creating notifications , Please help .

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Why not ? Its already available in iOS and android

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Go to settings > rings tones and sounds...now switch both ringer and vibrate to off. A new silent icon appears at the top.

Comment: The catch is solving this problem programmatically, not manually.